# Asking questions about relations

Tags: grammar

While we need to know a relations between two people, we usually say:

> What is the relation between X and Y?

Can we also say this in the following way?

> What is X to Y in relation?
>
> By relation what is X to Y?
>
> What relation is of X to Y?

Why these three occurred to me is because we may say [in affirmative sentence]:

> X is brother to Y.

Answer (score 2):

The first two would not be correct, because the use of 'to' already means you are asking about their relation, so you would instead say

> What is X to Y?

The third is almost correct, but you would place 'of' before 'what', since 'of' is part of the question, giving you

> Of what relation is X to Y?

or

> X is of what relation to Y?